# Creating a haskell function that prints and return a value

Tags: haskell

Here is my function:

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo i = do
    putStrLn "Foo Function has run!"
    return (i*2)
```

The above has a compile time error.

I want it to be the case that if I did this:

```
bar = foo 6
```

bar would be 12.

but when the function is first run, it prints out the string "Foo Function has run!"
How can i do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to make the function into an IO action.  Haskell strictly enforces that you separate code that does IO from code that doesn't:

```
foo :: Int -> IO Int
foo i = do
    putStrLn "Foo Function has run!"
    return (i * 2)
```

You could then extract this value inside another `IO` function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    bar1 <- foo 6
    bar2 <- foo bar1
    print (bar1, bar2)
```

The reasons why Haskell chooses this route are many and varied, but some of the important ones (in no particular order) are:

- Testability.  Any *pure* function is much easier to test because it always only depends on its inputs, not on the state of the application
- [Equational reasoning](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/12/equational-reasoning.html).  This means that you can reason about your code as if it were just fancy mathematical functions.  You can shuffle around your code much easier.
- Compiler optimizations.  The compiler is free to choose when and how to call your function if it has no side effects, it can defer the call until later, and it can make very tight inner loops in the compiled code that run much faster.
- Composability. Haskell type system is very rich, and segregating types in this fashion actually allows you to write more abstractions than you might be able to in C#, Java, or Python.
- Code clarity.  If you see a function just returns a value and not an IO action, you immediately know a lot about that function.  That type signature is a promise that you don't have to worry as much that the function might break your application.  On the other hand if it does return an IO action, this signifies that you have to be more careful.

Comment: Thats amazing but what if I didn't use Int but instead M.Map String Int. I tried "IO M.Map String Int" and "IO (M.Map String Int)" but both produce errors

Comment: @YahyaUddin What errors do they produce?  The second example you posted above should work just fine.  The `return` function is polymorphic in its argument and its return type, it will work with any type you give it.

Comment: @YahyaUddin The first example you posted above won't work because `IO M.Map String Int` is not a valid type, the `IO` type constructor only accepts one argument, while `M.Map` accepts two.  This is very much like function application where `g f a b` is very different from `g (f a b)`.  The form `IO (M.Map String Int)` is the correct one to use.

Comment: Thanks. I made a further mistake on another part hence the bracketed version did not work.

Comment: In particular, you could write a function `foo :: a -> IO a; foo a = do { putStrLn "Foo has been run"; return a }` that would work for any type you pass into it.  This function isn't particularly useful, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: will IO (M.Map String Int), allow math to be done on return values? or can you return an integer where further math can be done, such as.. ? bar1 <- foo 6, bar2 foo bar1, print(bar1+bar2)

Comment: @JosephPoirier Absolutely possible, otherwise it'd be pretty difficult to do anything at all besides printing out results.  Once you've extracted a value from some monad action `m a` with `<-` into a variable `x`, `x` just has type `a` and can be passed to any function that accepts that type.

Comment: I've found the values of the do, seem unretrievable. But without do all return.. What needs to be done to retrieve numeric values following a do in a multi-line HASKELL function?

Comment: @JosephPoirier If you have a question it might be best to ask it in its own post or to look around for an already answered question.

Comment: I'm locked out to ask questions.. for asking my first question in 2 years about 2 weeks ago. But I did resolve my haskell issue by putting all my math in one line. I just wanted it to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy on yourself, use `trace :: String -> a -> a` from `Debug.Trace`